# Mongoose stops to $push to array if the field already exists in a document

Tags: arrays, node.js, datetime, mongoose

I am using Node and Mongoose, and trying to set an array of `ISODate` elements:

```
    "visitLog" : [
                    ISODate("2017-10-22T22:43:49.571Z"),
                    ISODate("2017-10-22T22:44:39.572Z"),
                    ISODate("2017-10-22T23:35:36.111Z"),
                    ISODate("2017-10-22T23:48:26.516Z"),
                    ISODate("2017-10-22T23:50:33.378Z"),
                    ISODate("2017-10-22T23:53:56.227Z"),
                    ISODate("2017-10-22T23:57:20.986Z")
            ]
```

So I had an existing schema where `visitLog` field did not existed, added new field to a schema - `visitLog: [ {type: Date, default: '' }],`and it worked - the result is what you see above.
But when I created a new document with updated schema that already has an empty array in it - `"visitLog" : [ ]` , `$push` just stopped working.

Here is mongoose query, if needed:

```
    // conditions is a ternary operator that checks whether req.body username
    // is an email or not, and puts needed condition to a query
    var conditions = (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+$/.test(req.body.username)) ? ' {email: req.body.username } ' : ' {username: req.body.username } ';
    var fieldsToSet = {
          $push: {
            visitLog: new Date().toISOString(),
          }
        };
        var options = { upsert: true };     
        User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, fieldsToSet, options, function(err, user) { ...
```

The working document was created in mongo console, while the second was generated on a server, but I can't how can this make any difference.
Using `$push` shuld work with empty arrays. Can someone explain what's wrong here?

Thank you.

**Edit**

It figures that using `findByIdAndUpdate` without `conditions` works for both  documents:

```
var fieldsToSet = {
  $push: {
    visitLog: new Date().toISOString(),
  }
};
var options = { new: true };
req.app.db.models.User
.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, fieldsToSet, options, function(err, user) {
```

Comment: `$push` does work with empty arrays, and it really would not make sense for it not to. What specific error "if any" are you receiving? Note a few things such as making sure that `conditions` actually selects the document you expect, and that the statement only modifies the the "first" document found. Also be aware that `"upsert"` may be creating a new document if your `conditions` does not match anything, and that your `options` is missing `new: true`, which returns the "modifed" document as opposed to the original. That is the most probable cause of your misconception.

Comment: Also, as a sidenote the `default: ''` option within the array entry does not do what you think and actually has no effect at all in this context. If you are looking for an array with something in it "always", then that needs a different custom validation constraint. But it does not have any effect on this issue.

Comment: You are right, it's something wrong with `conditions`. I have changed `findOneAndUpdate` to `findByIdAndUpdate` and it worked for both documents. I have `passport.authenticate` before this so both `upsert` and `new` works. Thanks for the hint. But I still don't understand why it is working with one document and not pushing to another. I am not getting any errors on this. I will add the `conditions` as they were used in a query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the following query.

```
User.findOne(condiitons, (err, user) => {
  if (user) {
      var date = new Date().toISOString();
      user.visitLog.push(date);
      user.save();
      ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It must work with save, but it should also work using `findOneAndUpdate` or `findByIdAndUpdate` with `$push` and it didn't.

Comment: Try using user.markModified('visitLog') before user.save().